# C# Formatting a text file character by character into a 2D array in GUI

Tags: c#, arrays, user-interface, matrix

I have a text file:

> Berzas,sula;;sula;;klevu saldial lapasula  a   aila, ar  suart zemes vaikai du

I need to format it into a 2D array with `[n, n]` dimensions. It has to be a 2D array, i can't use a List

Here is what I have already tried:

```
string file = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Justas\Desktop\L1\Rekursija\Trecias.txt");

int n = 0;

while (Math.Pow(n, 2) != file.Length)  
{
    n++;
}

string[,] array = new string[n, n];

var list = Enumerable
.Range(0, file.Length / n)
.Select(i => file.Substring(i * n, n))
.ToList();
var res = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        array[i, j] = res[i].ToString()[j].ToString();
    }
}
```

I tried adding a new line every 9 positions and then adding it to the 2D array.

This is the error message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>      at System.String.get_Chars(Int32 index)
>      at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Justas\Desktop\Bandymas\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 37

Expected output:

```
Berzas,su
la;;sula;
;klevu sa
ldial lap
asula  a 
  aula, a
r  suart 
zemes vai
kai du
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail how the input relates to the desired output.

Comment: The `while` condition `Math.Pow(n, 2) != file.Length` can get you trapped in a infinite loop.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Why not just use Lists? Instead of `string[,] array = new string[n, n]` you could simply do `List<List<string>> array = new List<List<string>>();` removing the need to specify the size

Comment: @MindSwipe It is for an assignment, i can't use Lists, it has to be a 2D array

Comment: @Codor i updated the post with the desired outpout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a list then convert this list into string again. This is wrong.

In the below code i used your list values and apply split method for every list element.

Then I get all char values and put them into array.

In the last segment of the code i print array result. 
You can check array values from there.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            string file = "Berzas,sula;;sula;;klevu saldial lapasula a aila, ar suart zemes vaikai du       ";
            int n = 0;
            while (Math.Pow(n, 2) != file.Length)  
            {
                n++;
            }

            string[,] array = new string[n, n];

            var list = Enumerable
            .Range(0, file.Length / n)
            .Select(i => file.Substring(i * n, n))
            .ToList();

            var res = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                char[] row = list[i].ToCharArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    array[i, j] = row[j].ToString();
                }
            }

            int rowLength = array.GetLength(0);
            int colLength = array.GetLength(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0}", array[i, j]));
                }
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }

        }
    }
}
```